# GlobalAlloc, HeapAlloc - How can other process access Local Heap

Tags: c, windows, winapi, memory-management

**Context:**

I got this doubt when working on Clipboard implementation for a 32 bit Windows application in C/Win32 API.

As we know that Windows classic clipboard APIs expect us to pass a block of memory that should be global and shared (so that it could be accessed across process boundary). And most examples on MSDN/Web pass it a handle returned by GlobalAlloc(..) API.

Now as stated on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366533(v=vs.85).aspx) and explained by RaymondC in his blog [series](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041104-00/?p=37393):

> Starting with 32-bit Windows, GlobalAlloc().. and LocalAlloc() are implemented as wrapper functions that call HeapAlloc using a handle to the process's default heap. Therefore, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc have greater overhead than HeapAlloc.

**My Doubt:**

I understand that it all boils down to allocating memory from process's local heap. But what I am not able to understand is.. how will this work when there is a context switch? I mean the existing process's PD/PTEs will be updated to process being switched, and then these pages/allocated memory will no longer point to same physical memory.

Before reading MSDN, I'd assumed GlobalAlloc(..) will allocate memory in Kernel Space. But am still not able to understand how memory is being shared.

Related doubt: Who and when will block of memory be deallocated?

Additionally, it would be really helpful if someone can point me to source/documents containing slightly elaborate information regarding the same, so that I can demystify it once and for all.

Comment: It doesn't. Other processes can't access the memory allocated by GlobalAlloc any more than they could access memory allocated by HeapAlloc or malloc or new.

Comment: What *specific* clipboard API function are you having trouble with?

Comment: You are assuming that the clipboard shares memory somehow. This could very well be false; the clipboard could be copying everything. Or a program could be using `OleSetClipboard()`/`OleGetClipboard()` to copy OLE objects, and OLE will do the work for you. I don't know for sure. But this seems to be the question you would want answered. `GlobalAlloc()` is only global on 16-bit Windows because of how 16-bit Windows worked; the names are historical artifacts, but enough things use the functions that we keep them around. Raymond Chen has a few posts on his blog (The Old New Thing) on the issue.

Comment: @immibis thats correct and in sync with what I understand and have stated. But then why do i have to pass a GMEM_SHARED flag?

Comment: Also to answer @andlaabs I believe clipboard is not copying everything, since as per Petzold, _"However, because the memory blocks stored by the clipboard must be shared among applications running under Windows, the malloc function is inadequate for this task. 
"_. And anyway if clipboard needed to access, it can access anything, since its an OS component which would ideally have both Kernel/User memory access. BTW I've already gone though those posts.

Comment: Sounds like you've got an out-of-date copy of Petzold.  Or perhaps that bit of the text just got overlooked during revision.  [The documentation for GlobalAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366574(v=vs.85).aspx) is quite clear that the GMEM_SHARE flag is ignored.  See also [What was the point of the GMEM_SHARE flag?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041102-00/?p=37413)

Comment: ... FWIW, the clipboard might well use shared memory internally, but that's an implementation detail, subject to change.  All you need to worry about as a programmer is that you are correctly following the specifications of the API(s) you are using.  (If you are in doubt about the specifications for one or more API functions, go ahead and ask about them, but please be explicit.)  Note that to the best of my knowledge the clipboard is implemented entirely in user-mode, so it is unlikely to be "peeking" at other processes memory as you suggest.

Comment: @subdeveloper When they created 32-bit Windows they had to make it compatible with 16-bit Windows. So you still have to call the same function and pass the same flags even though it now does something different.

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks for your inputs. All three of your comments expect me to ask about specific API. But please understand this is not API specific, this is more of a curiosity based on general OS logic of cross-process memory sharing. It is no doubt implementation specific, and thats why I have marked Windows and WIndows-API in tags.

Comment: At a minimum, then, you should remove the part of the question about when memory will be deallocated, because obviously that can only be answered with regards to a specific API function.  Also, asking for off-site references is explicitly off-topic.  I'm not sure that the remainder of the question can be answered in any useful way, but perhaps if someone from MS comes along ...

Comment: Windows only provides two forms of shared memory to the application programmer, via .shared sections (for legacy support only, unsafe) or via the CreateFileMapping function.  *If* the clipboard uses shared memory, it will be using either CreateFileMapping or some undocumented internal function that serves a similar purpose.

Comment: Yes that's correct Harry and that's why i am wondering how? Since there is no mention of FileMappings etc in anything i have read regarding Clipboard. Anyway thanks for your help. I will wait and see if @RaymondChen or someone has a say on this.